# importing symbols from python package into caller's namespace

Tags: python, import, namespaces, package

I have a little internal DSL written in a single Python file that has grown to a point where I would like to split the contents across a number of different directories + files.

The new directory structure currently looks like this:

```
dsl/
    __init__.py
    types/
        __init__.py
        type1.py
        type2.py
```

and each type file contains a class (e.g. `Type1`).

My problem is that I would like to keep the implementation of code that uses this DSL as simple as possible, something like:

```
import dsl
x = Type1()
...
```

This means that all of the important symbols should be available directly in the user's namespace. I have tried updating the top-level `__init__.py` file to import the relevant symbols:

```
from types.type1 import Type1
from types.type2 import Type2
...
print globals()
```

the output shows that the symbols are imported correctly, but they still aren't present in the caller's code (the code that's doing the `import dsl`). I think that the problem is that the symbols are actually being imported to the 'dsl' namespace. How can I change this so that the classes are also directly available in the caller's namespace?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to say

```
from dsl import *
```

Comment: Actually the symbols are one level down from dsl. e.g. dsl.types.type1.

Comment: @WaiYipTung: Paul C says that he's updated the top-level `__init__.py` to include those symbols, so doing a `from dsl import *` should still work, even those symbols are originally defined one level down.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do

In dsl/init__.py, add

```
def import_symbols(namespace):
    namespace['type1'] = dsl.types.type1
    namespace['type2'] = dsl.types.type2
```

From the caller, do

```
import dsl

dsl.import_symbols(globals())
```

No only can you import symbols from a second level package into your current namespace, by defining you own `import_symbols()`, you also have more explicit control on which symbol to import rather than importing everythin with `import *`.

Answer (score 1):

@Eli, @Daniel thanks for the "aha" answer. I was almost there but needed the extra nudge...

Basically the solution was split into two stages: to use the package initialiser to pull the 'exported' second-level symbols into the top-level `dsl` package (this bit I already had) and then to pull *those* symbols into the caller's code with `from dsl import *`. This makes sense as the caller should really have control over what they pull into their namespace.

`from pkg import *` seems to be generally frowned on, but in this case I think it's a reasonable solution as the number of symbols exported by my package will be limited.

Comment: And how did you do this "pulling the second-level symbols into the top level `dsl` package"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. It's up to the user what they import into their own code. If they want to import everything into their namespace, they can do `from dsl import *`, but you can't dictate this.